# AWS Logs Insight - percent of failed DNS queries?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am currently learning about AWS Logs Insights, and I was wondering if the following is possible.

Let's say I gather logs from Route53. So I have an event for each query that reaches the AWS DNS servers of course. Now, I know I can count the number of queries per `resolverIp` for example as such:

```
stats count(*) by resolverIp
```

I also know that I can count the number of the queries, per resolverIp, that returned the NXDOMAIN responseCode, as such:

```
filter responseCode="NXDOMAIN" | stats count(*) by resolverIp
```

My question is, is there a way to get a percentage of the later (number of queries that returned NXDOMAIN per resolverIp) from the former (number of queries per resolverIp)?

Answer (score 0):

This query gives you the percentage sorted by resolver IP

```
 stats
   sum(strcontains(responseCode,"NXDOMAIN")) / count(*)
   * 100 by resolverIp
```